# How to SUM in JOIN, to avoid issue with two SUM in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, join, db2, ibm-midrange

I have read numerous posts regarding a similar issue, but none have lead to a solution so I am posting a new question. These are two in particular that address similar issues:

[SQL SELECT with multiple tables and SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017075/sql-select-with-multiple-tables-and-sum)

[How to write subquery inside the OUTER JOIN Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493512/how-to-write-subquery-inside-the-inner-join-statement)

This is the first version of the code I had and the issue it created. This is in a DB2 for iSeries database. I just get a generic `ODBC error 1004`, which means the SQL is fine, but the database doesn't like something about the code. I have verified table names and column names are correct.

```
SELECT i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT Item, i.INAME DESC1, i.INAME2 DESC2, 
       i.IPOL1 PC1, i.IPOL2 PC2, i.IPOL3 PC3, SUM(s.JONHAN) QOH, i.IUNITS UM, 
       SUM(inv.INEXTP) Sales, i.IINVEN INV, i.ICCTR CC, i.ICLAS1 I1, i.IDISCD DDate, 
       i.ILPODT LOrder, i.IAVGC AVGC 
FROM QS36F.ITEM i
JOIN QS36F.ITEMSTK s
     ON i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT = s.JMFGR || s.JCOLOR || s.JPAT
        JOIN QS36F.INVOICED inv
     ON inv.INMFGR || inv.INCOLO || inv.INPATT = i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT
WHERE (i.IMFGR = '" & man & "') AND ((i.IPOL1 = 'SP') OR (i.IPOL2 = 'SP') OR 
      (i.IPOL3 = 'SP') OR (i.IPOL1 = 'DI') OR (i.IPOL2 = 'DI') OR (i.IPOL3 = 'DI'))
GROUP BY i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT, i.INAME, i.INAME2, i.IPOL1, i.IPOL2, i.IPOL3, 
         i.IUNITS, i.IINVEN, i.ICCTR, i.ICLAS1, i.IDISCD, i.ILPODT, i.IAVGC
ORDER BY i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT
```

This wasn't working because it was causing the `SUM(s.JONHAN) QOH` to be multiplied many times over, so is thus inaccurate.

After reading some threads, it looks like I need to put the second `SUM` in a `JOIN` statement. However, I am still getting an `ODBC error 1004`, so I am not sure what I missing.

```
SELECT i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT Item, i.INAME DESC1, i.INAME2 DESC2, 
       i.IPOL1 PC1, i.IPOL2 PC2, i.IPOL3 PC3, SUM(s.JONHAN) QOH, i.IUNITS UM, 
       inv.Sales, i.IINVEN INV, i.ICCTR CC, i.ICLAS1 I1, i.IDISCD DDate,
       i.ILPODT LOrder, i.IAVGC AVGC 
FROM QS36F.ITEM i
JOIN QS36F.ITEMSTK s
     ON i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT = s.JMFGR || s.JCOLOR || s.JPAT
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT INMFGR || INCOLO || INPATT Item, SUM(INEXTP) Sales
                 FROM QS36F.INVOICED
                 GROUP BY INMFGR, INCOLO, INPATT) inv
                     ON inv.Item = i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT
WHERE (i.IMFGR = '" & man & "') AND ((i.IPOL1 = 'SP') OR (i.IPOL2 = 'SP') OR 
      (i.IPOL3 = 'SP') OR (i.IPOL1 = 'DI') OR (i.IPOL2 = 'DI') OR (i.IPOL3 = 'DI'))
GROUP BY i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT, i.INAME, i.INAME2, i.IPOL1, i.IPOL2, i.IPOL3, 
         i.IUNITS, i.IINVEN, i.ICCTR, i.ICLAS1, i.IDISCD, i.ILPODT, i.IAVGC
ORDER BY i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT
```

Everything plays nice until the second `SUM` and `JOIN` statement is added. I can do a query on the `SELECT` in the second `JOIN` and it runs as it should.

Comment: The excerpt: `i.IMFGR = '" & man & "'` indicates that this code is probably vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Perhaps not. if the above is the statement as sent to DB2 for i, then it's literally the string '" & man &"', single quotes are the string delimiters.  || is the concatenation operator.  OTOH, if the above is a string being built in VB where & is the concatenation operator...then yeah I'd agree with you.

Comment: The reason why Charles is pointing out that concatenating join and group columns is bad is that it'll force the db to completely ignore any indicies.  In other words, for a table of any real size, it's going to be ridiculously slow.  Which could be why it's unhappy, because you've asked it to do way to much work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, this:

```
JOIN QS36F.ITEMSTK s
     ON i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT = s.JMFGR || s.JCOLOR || s.JPAT
```

Is a bad idea, it should really be

```
JOIN QS36F.ITEMSTK s
     ON i.IMFGR = s.JMFGR
        and i.ICOLOR = s.JCOLOR 
        and i.IPATT =  s.JPAT
```

Secondly, I don't see anything obviously wrong.  It'd help if you could look at the joblog of the QZDASOINIT job servicing the ODBC request and report the actual error thrown by DB2.

Having said that, my preference is for Common Table Expressions (CTE) as opposed to Nested Table Expressions (NTE)

```
WITH inv as (SELECT INMFGR, INCOLO, INPATT, SUM(INEXTP) Sales
               FROM QS36F.INVOICED
              GROUP BY INMFGR, INCOLO, INPATT
             )
, s as (SELECT JMFGR, JCOLOR, JPAT, sum(JOHHAN) TotalOH
          FROM QS36F.ITEMSTK
         GROUP BY JMFGR, JCOLOR, JPAT
       )
SELECT i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT Item, i.INAME DESC1, i.INAME2 DESC2, 
       i.IPOL1 PC1, i.IPOL2 PC2, i.IPOL3 PC3, s.TotalOH QOH, i.IUNITS UM, 
       inv.Sales, i.IINVEN INV, i.ICCTR CC, i.ICLAS1 I1, i.IDISCD DDate,
       i.ILPODT LOrder, i.IAVGC AVGC 
FROM QS36F.ITEM i
JOIN s
      ON i.IMFGR = s.INMFGR
         and i.ICOLOR = s.INCOLOR 
         and i.IPATT =  s.INPATT
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv
       ON i.IMFGR = inv.JMFGR
            and i.ICOLOR = inv.JCOLOR 
            and i.IPATT =  inv.JPAT
WHERE (i.IMFGR = '" & man & "') AND ((i.IPOL1 = 'SP') OR (i.IPOL2 = 'SP') OR 
      (i.IPOL3 = 'SP') OR (i.IPOL1 = 'DI') OR (i.IPOL2 = 'DI') OR (i.IPOL3 = 'DI'))
ORDER BY i.IMFGR, i.ICOLOR, i.IPATT
```

Comment: You can probably order by individual columns, not the concatenation.  Especially if you're not joining by the concatenation...